# How do i map points from one grid to another?

Tags: c#, .net, grid

Let's say i have a 2d linear grid and a point in said grid. How do i map the point from that grid into a related non-linear grid?

[image: example image]

The red dot is the point in the regular grid and i want to know how to figure out where the point would go in a similar deformed grid (an example one is shown). I'm thinking of using the difference between the points in the non-deformed grid and the deformed one to derive a solution but i'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read up on [Affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). There isn't much magic going on here, just a little translation and [shearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Shearing). This is all done just with a matrix multiplication for the coordinate pairs (in [homogenous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates)), so it's very easy to do. But can be a little hard to understand :-)

Comment: It's quite possible that the deformed points could be in extremely unusual configurations, will it work for those cases? (such as the lower right point being very close to and/or on the other side of the upper left)

Comment: Well, as long as you can represent it with scaling, shearing, rotation, it should be possible. Also there are perspective transformations which are a little harder to calculate but have pretty much the same underlying mathematics.